# Sonar 'Possible null pointer dereference' error on almost every method call

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am fetching some data from a remote service using Spring's RestTemplate:

```
ResponseEntity<....> result = restTemplate.exchange(....);
```

...and then I am using result for further processing, and hence I am invoking various methods on it, like:

```
result.getHeaders().getContentType().getType()
result.getBody()
result.getHeaders().getContentType().getSubtype()
```

Sonar doesn't like this code and reports 'Possible null pointer dereference' error on almost all of these method calls. It seems I need to have null check on almost every return value.

This makes my code with too many null checks.

Can this be avoided?

Comment: Yes, turn off the check

Comment: That's not in my hand. Its team level setting.

Comment: Then make sure you prematurely avoid NPEs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Optional` from java 8 [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
String contentType = Optional.ofNullable(result)
  .map(HttpResponse::getHeaders)
  .map(Headers::getContentType)
  .map(ContentType::getType)
  .orElse(null);
```

`HttpResponse` should be the type of `result`, `Headers` should be the return type of `getHeaders()` and so on.

You can use other terminating operators other than `orElse()`:

```
.orElseGet(() -> someOtherProcess());
.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Content Type was Null"));
```